# Specifying attribute values as CDATA

Tags: xml, validation

Can one specify XML attribute values as CDATA ? If yes - what would be the schema for the same. If not - why is this limitation not addressed in XML ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you cannot do this.

There's a very fine line (and a very large debate) between what constitutes an attribute and what constitutes a child element. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152313/xml-attributes-vs-elements) for example.

That given, the "limitation" isn't addressed in XML because it doesn't exist. You always have the ability to put this data in a child element, and in fact I would go so far as to say that if you even have to think about this, an element is the correct structure.

Edit: More reading material

- [The Attribute/Text Conundrum](http://xmleverywhere.com/newsletters/20000525.htm)
- [Principles of XML design: When to use elements versus attributesl](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleatt.html)
- [w3schools take](http://www.w3schools.com/DTD/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp)

Comment: OK, but if I'm not designing anything but simply trying to uses someone else's DTD/Schema, and need to supply an attribute value that contains illegal characters, what are my options?

Answer (score 1):

The way you handle that is to use a child element rather than an attribute.