# xml error code file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

we are thinking use xml file to store our error codes for our C# application. for the following two structures, which one is better?

```
<error>
<code>0x00000001</code>
<description>Error PIB: Clamp</description>
<reaction>Display</reaction>
</error>
```

or

```
<error code=0x00000001 >
<description>Error PIB: Clamp</description>
<reaction>Display</reaction>
</error>
```

or your better suggestion?

seems the second one save some space and easiler for lookup through it?

I need to get the `description` and `reaction` string by lookup the `error code`. do you have an effective way to lookup through file?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152313/xml-attributes-vs-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were after *space-saving* techniques, I would suggest not using XML in the first place :)

Personally I prefer the second approach over the first, but both will work. If this is really just for lookup, I'd suggest that when you load the file, you convert it to a `Dictionary<String, ErrorInformation>` or something similar. (You could make the key value a numeric type instead, but that would require parsing the value of course.)

LINQ to XML makes it really easy to do this sort of conversion:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("errorcodes.xml");
var dictionary = xml.Descendants("error")
                    .ToDictionary(element => (string) element.Attribute("code"),
                                  element => new ErrorInformation(
                                      (string) element.Element("description"),
                                      (string) element.Element("reaction")));
```

Comment: +1, xml != space-saving.  For space saving, you could go with something like JSON objects.  There is a lot less info stored in JSON compared to XML.  Only, XML is a lot easier to deal with in the code.  If space isn't that big of a deal, I really like the approach given here.  It's very simple and understandable

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want the `code` to describe the element, make it an attribute.  If you want the `code` to be an element (meaning that the `code` will also require attributes or even sub information) make it a child.

In your code, option 2 is best IMO