# using AutoMapper for map XML to Object with List Property

Tags: c#, xml, automapper

I know the basics of right way for map XML to strongly type objects but my received XML from service is different!
my XMl is like this:

```
<Group>
    <Title>friends</Title>
    <Member>
        <Name>Omid</Name>
    </Member>
    <Member>
        <Name>Kourosh</Name>
    </Member>
<Group>
```

and my object is:

```
public class Group
{
    public string Title { get; set; };
    public ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; };
}
```

so when I try to map XElement (from XML) to Group then Members don't map :(
whats the best way? 
changing XML? 
using specific config for AutoMapper? 
and how?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally read [this useful article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/706992/Using-AutoMapper-with-Complex-XML-Data) and change the _mapItems to this to solve my problem:

```
private static Func<XElement, string, List<XElement>> _mapItems =
    (src, elementName) =>
    src.Elements(elementName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the same [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/706992/Using-AutoMapper-with-Complex-XML-Data) and found that there was an XML format difference with my code. Mine was XML Element as compared to XML Attribute as suggested in article.
Here is a StackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152313/xml-attributes-vs-elements) if someone needs more information.My XML was element based and not attribute based.

My XML was something like below and my challenge was to read multiple accounts

```
<consumer>
<id>XYZ</id>   
<birthDate>1990-05-22</birthDate>   
<accounts>
  <account>
    <id>123</id>
    <regdate>2014-05-22</regdate>        
  </account>
</accounts>
```

My code was the same as in article but I changed the MapItems function to following

```
private static readonly Func<XElement, string, string, List<XElement>> MapItems =
        (src, collectionName, elementName) =>
        (src.Element(collectionName) ?? new XElement(collectionName)).Elements(elementName).ToList();
```

When doing the mapping, I mapped it as follows

```
.ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Accounts,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => MapItems(src, "accounts", "account")));
```